# /etc/skel doesn't work with xenial

Tags: server, ldap, user-profile, skel

We have a script which works perfectly with Xubuntu 14.04 and an Ubuntu Server with ldap : https://github.com/dane-lyon/clients-linux-scribe/blob/master/ubuntu-et-variantes-integrdom.sh

We use /etc/skel in order to configure new ldap user.

With Xenial, a new user doesn't receive /etc/skel in his profile. We don't know why ? Any idea ?

Thanks !

PS :

- users are created on the LDAP Server
- home directories are created on logon with pam_mkhomedir.so (https://github.com/dane-lyon/clients-linux-scribe/blob/master/ubuntu-et-variantes-integrdom.sh#L227)
- user's home contains nothing at all after logon

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more detail. How are the new users created? What exact commands do you use to create them? Do you also create their home directories? What does the new user's home directory contain (nothing at all? Some files from `/etc/skel` but not all?).

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, fun fact, I have 2 xenial ltsp servers, only one of them is affected.

Comment: Can you post the configuration you've used for `pam_mkhomedir`?